# VideoJS is intermittently choppy on Blackberry10

Tags: html, video, blackberry-10

You can reproduce this by going to:
VideoJS.com

and playing the video as the page loads.

Sometimes the video plays perfectly, sometimes it's a garbled mess.  Video bufferes ahead of playback but is still choppy.

Tested on Z10 and blackberry simulator.

I'd like to prevent this from happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended one run video on a simulator or opengl. However, if the hardware can enable Virtualization extensions from the BIOS.

http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/simulator_systemrequirements.html

Comment: Right, though the problem exists on the Z-10 device as well, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it on my Z10 and it ran very smoothly. Is there a software update available for your device?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I don't use BB regularly.  Only reason I have access to one is to test this very issue.  I'm going to click around to see what I can find.

Right now we have a work-around where the video fires in a modal that doesn't allow the video to play until the DOM is ready.  Not sure if I like the modal approach though.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: What's the model number of your device (under Settings->About)?